# celery with ProcessPoolExecutor return ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, celery, concurrent.futures

I'm using celery with concurrent.futures,but the program returns ModuleNotFoundError.

I use ProcessPoolExecutor but failed, but when I change it to ThreadPoolExecutor, it seems OK.

This is the strture of my test proejct:

```
test/
  _celery.py
  main.py
  lib/
    task/
        test.py
```

_celery.py:

```
from celery import Celery
from lib.task import test

app = Celery(broker_url='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', 
celery_result_backend='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def test_(word_list):
    test.test(word_list)
```

lib/task/test.py:

```
import concurrent.futures


def process(word):
    return word


def test(word_list):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future_process = {executor.submit(process, word): word for word in word_list}
```

main.py:

```
from _celery import test_

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_.delay(['test1', 'test2', 'test3'])
```

And I use this command to start celery service:

```
celery -A _celery worker -l info --pool=solo
```

Actually the terminal returns:

```
[2019-08-28 15:30:05,116: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: _celery.test_[d8e4d74d-4c32-44a8-a468-eeed92079258]
Process SpawnProcess-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\wind\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\wind\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\users\wind\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 233, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True)
  File "c:\users\wind\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 113, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
[2019-08-28 15:30:06,711: INFO/MainProcess] Task _celery.test_[d8e4d74d-4c32-44a8-a468-eeed92079258] succeeded in 1.5940000000009604s: None
```

If I don't use celery and directly invoke test.test() in main.py, it's OK and I'm confused.

I am searching for a long time on net but no use. Please help me or try to give me some ideas on how to resolve this.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'` means Python can't find that package, so it is not in the PYTHONPATH... Try: `export PYTHONPATH=path/to/dir/where/lib/is` and try again (replacing path/to/test to directory above the lib )

Comment: Thanks.I import sys and used sys.path.append('C:/Users/wind/Desktop/test/') to add the path,but the problem still exist.